# Get Highest number in DataGridView Column without clicking a row, to generate ID field on another form. (C# Windows Forms App)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying get the value of the highest number in a DataGridView column, so that I can populate a text field on a separate form with that value +1, I can't seem to find a working method for .Max, or a solution that matches this specific need.

In my limited experience with Python, I seem to remember being able to get the last value in an array by using [-1] or something similar, does c# have anything like this?

Here is my code to populate the Text field on the 2nd form, with the Column value of the DataGridView on the first:

```
public AddPart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainScreen frm1 = new MainScreen();
        AddPartIDBox.Text = frm1.PartDGV.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

[image]

[image]

Here's what I'm needing it to do, if I have ID 0, 1, I need that text field to populate with 2, so that it saves the new part with the next available number.

Note:
The 2 parts (ID 0 and ID 1) are manually coded into Program.cs to add, the part constructor uses an integer IncrementID to set the ID field with PartID = IncremementID++;

Comment: `frm1.PartDGV.Rows[frm1.PartDGV.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Value`?? I think what you want is the `.Count` property of the `.Rows` property of the `DataGridView`. This minus one will give you the last element in the collection. This will only work if the items are in ascending order by the PartID

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I'll post what I did as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ryan Wilson, I was able to get it working. Here is the code snippet:

```
int dgvIndex = (int)frm1.PartDGV.Rows[frm1.PartDGV.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Value; 
        int dgvIndex2 = dgvIndex + 1;
        AddPartIDBox.Text = dgvIndex2.ToString();
```

Comment: Please remember [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Thank you,

Comment: @RyanWilson thank you for your comment. I hope OP accepts their own answer and so the question wont be *unanswered*.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes I was wrong, it's actually 48 hours that you have to wait from the time you posted the question to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case your `DataGridView` can be manipulated to re-order the rows, it may be better to find the `MAX` `PartID`. You can achieve this in multiple ways, but for sake of doing it with few lines of code, I am going to use `Linq`:

```
int maxpartid = frm1.PartDGV.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                  .Max(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Cells[0].Value));
```